# How to prove that the product of two $C^\infty$ functions is also a $C^\infty$ function rigorously?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

How to prove that the product of two $C^\infty$ functions is also a $C^\infty$ function?

I guess it is easy to prove the above fact by induction, but I cannot prove that.

Let $f, g$ be $C^\infty$ functions from an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.
Prove that $f g$ is also a $C^\infty$ function from an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

My attemp is here:

> $D_i f$ is also a $C^\infty$ function for any $i \in \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$.
> $D_i g$ is also a $C^\infty$ function for any $i \in \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$.
> $D_i (f g) = D_i(f) g + f D_i(g)$ and $D_i f, D_i g$ are $C^\infty$ functions.
> It is enough to prove that $D_i(f) g$ and $f D_i(g)$ are $C^\infty$ functions.
> But to prove that $D_i(f) g$ and $f D_i(g)$ are $C^\infty$ functions, we need to prove the product of two $C^\infty$ functions is also a $C^\infty$ function.
> A circular argument?

Comment: You are correct that your attempt results in a circular argument. Study the proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule#Proof).

Comment: If you prove that $fg$ is $C^k$ for all $k$, you only need that $D_i(f)g$ and $fD_i(g)$ are $C^{k-1}$, which you can get from induction.

Comment: @RagibZaman Thank you very much.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S := \{f | f = \sum_{i = 1}^n g_i h_i \text{ for some } n, g_i \text{ and } h_i \text{ are } C^\infty \text{ functions.}\}$.

Let $f \in S$. Then, we can write $f = \sum_{i = 1}^n g_i h_i$ for some $n$, where $g_i$ and $h_i$ are $C^\infty$ functions.

Then $f$ is differentiable and $\frac{d}{dx} f = \sum_{i = 1}^n g_i^{'} h_i + \sum_{i = 1}^n g_i h_i^{'}$ and $g_i^{'}$ and $h_i^{'}$ are $C^\infty$ functions.

So, $\frac{d}{dx} f \in S$.

So, $S$ is closed under the operation $\frac{d}{dx}$.

If $f$ and $g$ are $C^\infty$ functions, then $f g \in S$.
Since any element of $S$ is differentiable and $S$ is closed under the operation $\frac{d}{dx}$, $f g$ is a $C^\infty$ function.